# How to draw a shape generated by several functions in GLSL?

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

[image]

I tried to draw a complex shape with GLSL,which generated by 4 function images,they were

1. **x^2+y^2=1**
2. **y=0.8*log(0.63*x+0.64)+0.8**
3. **y=0.5*log(10*x-2)+1**
4. **y=-0.1(x+-0.5)^2+1.8**

Here is the shape I drew in desmos:[Magatama](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7yvsdsverk).

And this is what I have implemented so far:[sharingan](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltGfDV)

I want to pick out this part in my fragment shader:
[image]

I don't know how to pick out.Hope someone can provide some ideas.

THX.

Comment: and what exactly is the problem? You got one shape and what to have also its 2 rotated copies? simply create a function inside shader that has x,y as input and boolean output telling if coordinate is inside ... and in main just call it 3 times each with rotated  `x,y` values ... and or the result together ... if true render black otherwise red ...

Comment: Sry,@Spektre I update my question.I want to draw the red part of the picture above,and I don't know how to do.I mean what you said, but I don’t know how to achieve it.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite the equations (border) to system of inequalities (inside) so you can decide if fragment is inside your shape or not ...  for example **#1** would be `x^2+y^2<=1` ... inside unit circle ... if all the functions are true fragment is inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GLSL language provides functions like [`log(x)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/log.xhtml) or [`pow`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/pow.xhtml) to do powerful calculations. See [GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6; Chapter 8. Built-In Functions; page 152](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf) for a full set of functions.

e.g.

```c
float y1 = 0.4*log(0.63*x+0.64)+1.8;
```

To draw a shape like this you have to draw a quad in screen space pass the normalized device x and y coordinates to the fragment shader. The bottom left coordinate is (-1, -1), the top right is (1, 1) and of course the center is 0.0.

To find the area which is "in" the shape, you have to turn the result of the calculations into atomic statements. Use the [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml)  function to compare a value to an edge and to get 1.0 if the result is true or 0.0 if the result is false.

e.g. test if a coordinate is in a circle:

```c
float a0 = step(x*x + y*y, 1.0);
```

e.g. test if a `y` coordinate, calculated by *f(x)* is less "under" (less) the curve of formed by a function:

```c
  float y3 = -0.1 * pow(x+-0.5, 2.0)+1.8;
  float a3 = step(y, y3);
```

To find out if a fragment is in the form you have the results of the different calculations by "logical" operations on floating point values.

e.g. a logical *OR* operation can be calculated by the [`max`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/max.xhtml) function:

```c
float a = max(a0, a1); // a := a0 OR a1
```

e.g. a logical *AND* operation can be calculated by the multiplication operator or the [`min`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/min.xhtml) function:

```c
float a = a0 * a1; // a := a0 AND a1
```

Use the final result to set the output color. The [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) function can be used to interpolate between 2 colors. Since the "logocal" result of the calculations is either 0.0 or 1.0, the `mix` function is use to "select" on of the 2 colors:

```
vec3 col_fill = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // red
vec3 col_back = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // black

vec4 frag_color = vec4(mix(col_back, col_fill, a), 1.0);
```

See the WebGL example, which uses a fragment shader with this technique to generate a shape similar that on of the question. The formulas are slightly adapted, since the formulas of the question doesn't generate the expected result. The logical results of the different parts of the shape are represented in different colors:

```js
(function loadscene() {

var gl, canvas, prog, bufObj = {};

function render(deltaMS) {

  gl.viewport( 0, 0, vp_size[0], vp_size[1] );
  gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
  gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
  ShProg.Use( progDraw );
  ShProg.SetF2( progDraw, "resolution", vp_size );
  VertexBuffer.Draw( bufRect );

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}  

function initScene() {

  canvas = document.getElementById( "texture-canvas");
  gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
  //gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl2" );
  if ( !gl )
    return;
    
  progDraw = ShProg.Create( 
    [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
      { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
    ] );
  progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.progObj, "inPos" );
  if ( progDraw.progObj == 0 )
      return;

  bufRect = VertexBuffer.Create(
  [ { data :  [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ], attrSize : 2, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos } ],
    [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ] );

  window.onresize = resize;
  resize();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
  //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
  vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
  vp_size[0] = vp_size[1] = Math.min(vp_size[0], vp_size[1]); 
  //vp_size = [256, 256]
  canvas.width = vp_size[0];
  canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

var ShProg = {
Create: function (shaderList) {
  var shaderObjs = [];
  for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++i_sh) {
      var shderObj = this.Compile(shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage);
      if (shderObj) shaderObjs.push(shderObj);
  }
  var prog = {}
  prog.progObj = this.Link(shaderObjs)
  if (prog.progObj) {
      prog.attrInx = {};
      var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
      for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++i_n) {
          var name = gl.getActiveAttrib(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
          prog.attrInx[name] = gl.getAttribLocation(prog.progObj, name);
      }
      prog.uniLoc = {};
      var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS);
      for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++i_n) {
          var name = gl.getActiveUniform(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
          prog.uniLoc[name] = gl.getUniformLocation(prog.progObj, name);
      }
  }
  return prog;
},
AttrI: function (prog, name) { return prog.attrInx[name]; },
UniformL: function (prog, name) { return prog.uniLoc[name]; },
Use: function (prog) { gl.useProgram(prog.progObj); },
SetI1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1i(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1f(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF2: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform2fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF3: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF4: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetM33: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
SetM44: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
Compile: function (source, shaderStage) {
  var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
  if (shaderScript)
      source = shaderScript.text;
  var shaderObj = gl.createShader(shaderStage);
  gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
  gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
  var status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
  return status ? shaderObj : null;
},
Link: function (shaderObjs) {
  var prog = gl.createProgram();
  for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++i_sh)
      gl.attachShader(prog, shaderObjs[i_sh]);
  gl.linkProgram(prog);
  status = gl.getProgramParameter(prog, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(prog));
  return status ? prog : null;
} };

var VertexBuffer = {
Create: function(attribs, indices, type) {
  var buffer = { buf: [], attr: [], inx: gl.createBuffer(), inxLen: indices.length, primitive_type: type ? type : gl.TRIANGLES };
  for (var i=0; i<attribs.length; ++i) {
      buffer.buf.push(gl.createBuffer());
      buffer.attr.push({ size : attribs[i].attrSize, loc : attribs[i].attrLoc, no_of: attribs[i].data.length/attribs[i].attrSize });
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i]);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attribs[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  }
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  if ( buffer.inxLen > 0 ) {
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  }
  return buffer;
},
Draw: function(bufObj) {
  for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i) {
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i]);
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc);
  }
  if ( bufObj.inxLen > 0 ) {
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx);
      gl.drawElements(bufObj.primitive_type, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
  }
  else
      gl.drawArrays(bufObj.primitive_type, 0, bufObj.attr[0].no_of );
  for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i)
      gl.disableVertexAttribArray(bufObj.attr[i].loc);
  gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
} };

initScene();

})();
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
  
uniform vec2 resolution;
varying vec2 vpos;

vec3 col_fill = vec3(0.6);
vec3 col_back = vec3(0.0);

float scale = 3.0;

void main( void )
{
    vec2 pos = scale * vpos;
    float x = pos.x;
    float y = pos.y;

    float a0 = step(x*x + y*y, 1.0); 
    
    float y1 = 0.4*log(0.63*x+0.64)+1.8;
    float a1 = step(y, y1);

    float y2 = 0.3*log(10.0*x-2.0)+0.8;
    float a2 = step(y2, y) + step(x,0.2);

    float y3 = -0.1 * pow(x+-0.5, 2.0)+1.8;
    float a3 = step(y, y3);

    float a = max(a0, a1*a2*a3*step(0.0,y));

    vec3 rgb = mix(col_back, col_fill, a) + 0.4 * vec3(a1, a2, a3);
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;
varying vec2 vpos;

void main()
{
    vpos = inPos.xy; 
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<canvas id="texture-canvas" style="border: none"></canvas>
```

Comment: I wanna worship the ground you walks on!

Comment: @SmartCoder You're welcome. It was a pleasure to help.